# Spring - conventional way to create a @Bean before another @Bean loaded from the library

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mocking

So, I have a few dependencies which I'm trying to mock for integration tests.

More specifically, I have a `spring-cloud` on my classpath which loads a `Eureka client` as part of its bootstrap configuration process, and tries to connect to `discovery service`.

Currently, I'm using a real server, but I'd like to mock it, before the client attempts to connect to it.

Unfortunately, as client is included in the library, I have no control over it, i.e. I can't add a `@DependsOn` annotation to it.

I was playing with various Spring lifecycle listeners and I think I should be able to get it to work, but was wondering if there is a cleaner approach to solve the problem.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34307529/strategy-for-unit-testing-a-spring-cloud-service) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable eureka for you integration-test with the following property 
`"eureka.client.enabled:false"`

---

Another way is to produces a mock eureka bean with the [@Primary](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html)  annotation on it. This strategy is the opposite of setting @DependsOn.

> Indicates that a bean should be given preference when multiple
>   candidates are qualified to autowire a single-valued dependency. If
>   exactly one 'primary' bean exists among the candidates, it will be the
>   autowired value.