# How to disable Eureka and Spring Cloud Config in a WebMvcTest?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-config

I play with a simple Spring Boot application which registers itself in Eureka and uses spring cloud configuration to read some properties.

Here it goes:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

In `bootstrap.yml` I have:

```
eureka:
    client:
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: http://registry-service:5051/eureka/

spring:
    application:
        name: product-service
    cloud:
        config:
            discovery:
                serviceId: config-service
                enabled: true
            fail-fast: true
            retry:
                initial-interval: 2000
```

I have a rest controller for which I want to write a test. The test will use mockMVC. Simplified example follows:

The controller:

```
@RestController
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, 
            value = "/api/products", 
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Product> createProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {

        ...
        return ...;
    }
}
```

The test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(ProductController.class)
public class ProductControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private ProductService mockProductService;


    @Test
    public void testProductFound() {
        ...
    }
}
```

If I start this test it will fail because it will try to auto-configure the mock MVC but before that it try to register the app in Eureka. It will also attempt to fetch configurations from a config service. Neither of these services run during the test execution of course. I want to disable them.

I tried many things. For example I tried to annotate the test case with:

```
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application-controller-tests.properties")
```

Within the properties there is:

```
spring.cloud.discovery.enabled = false
spring.cloud.config.enabled = false
```

Theoretically it seems that this should work but the test still spits exceptions like this one:

```
017-06-11 19:10:56.549  INFO 11508 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Disable delta property : false
2017-06-11 19:10:56.549  INFO 11508 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Single vip registry refresh property : null
2017-06-11 19:10:56.549  INFO 11508 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Force full registry fetch : false
2017-06-11 19:10:56.549  INFO 11508 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application is null : false
2017-06-11 19:10:56.549  INFO 11508 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Registered Applications size is zero : true
2017-06-11 19:10:56.549  INFO 11508 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application version is -1: true
2017-06-11 19:10:56.549  INFO 11508 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2017-06-11 19:10:57.683 ERROR 11508 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error

com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:509) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplicationsInternal(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:194) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplications(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:165) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:118) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:79) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:119) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1030) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:944) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:444) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:304) [eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.<init>(CloudEurekaClient.java:51) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$EurekaClientConfiguration.eurekaClient(EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java:162) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$EurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bec65081.CGLIB$eurekaClient$0(<generated>) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$EurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bec65081$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$97f6772b.invoke(<generated>) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$EurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bec65081.eurekaClient(<generated>) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:138) [spring-cloud-context-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:1.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:84) [spring-cloud-context-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:1.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:62) [spring-cloud-context-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:1.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:73) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:336) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120) [spring-boot-test-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) [spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) [spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83) [spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117) [spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) [spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44) [spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230) [spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228) [spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287) [spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247) [spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94) [spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191) [spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:117) ~[httpclient-4.5.jar:4.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177) ~[httpclient-4.5.jar:4.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144) ~[httpclient-4.5.jar:4.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131) ~[httpclient-4.5.jar:4.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611) ~[httpclient-4.5.jar:4.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446) ~[httpclient-4.5.jar:4.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:882) ~[httpclient-4.5.jar:4.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:117) ~[httpclient-4.5.jar:4.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55) ~[httpclient-4.5.jar:4.5]
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    ... 119 common frames omitted
```

What is the correct way to disable Eureka and the cloud config when testing the controllers?

Comment: easiest way with slice tests like `@WebMvcTest` is to externalise the `@Enables...` to a separate configuration. Slice tests read from the Application class and will try to enable annotations/init any beans it finds. Not sure on the cloud config aspect personally.

Answer (score 26):

I've found a way to make these tests run with relatively simple test configuration.

Specifying these properties seems OK:

```
#Disable discovery
spring.cloud.discovery.enabled = false

#Disable cloud config and config discovery
spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled = false
spring.cloud.config.enabled = false
```

A base test class is annotated like this:

```
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-controller-tests.properties")
```

The test itself brings the following annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = ProductController.class, secure = false)
```

Then the mock MVC is wired and configured like this:

```
@Autowired
protected MockMvc mockMvc;
```

I'm still not sure if this is the "elegant" way or I should use profiles or..

Comment: This is old one : spring.cloud.discovery.enabled = false

Please use this one : "eureka.client.enabled=false" to disable eureka service registration in test.

Comment: Creating the property file worked, but I had to use "spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled = false" to exclude classes included in the bootstrap configuration in META-INF/spring.factories

Answer (score 2):

faced similar issue while executing springboot test.
[Error Snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5QlG.png)

To Resolve Error Creating Eureka bean while testing.

Add eureka.client.enabled= false
**In application.properties file in test resource**

Comment: Hi, please refrain from posting code/error messages/etc. as images. That makes it unneccesarily hard to track down potentially good answers :)

Comment: Be aware that this approach works but will have an effect that might not be expected: your `application.properties` under `src/test/resources` will replace the whole default `application.properties` file therefore you need to include all the required properties on your test file. I find it better to use `application-test.properties` and activate the test profile via `@ActiveProfiles("test")`.

Answer (score 1):

Move your Eureka configuration (`@EnableEurekaClient`) to a separate configuration class and make it enabled conditionally using `@ConditionalOnProperty`.
Review answer to the following question to get more precise instructions:
[Strategy for unit testing a Spring Cloud Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34307529/strategy-for-unit-testing-a-spring-cloud-service)

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I'm using both Eureka and Spring Cloud Config, so disabling only Eureka does not seem to work very well. I've found another solution which seems somehow decent. I'll post it a moment.

Answer (score -1):

if u switch that `spring.cloud.config.fail-fast=false`, that will work. but that will break your fail-fast thing.