# How to exclude bootstrapping in META-INF/spring.factories from java tests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test, spring-cloud-config

Had this line in resources/META-INF/spring.factories:
`org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=org.path.to.AWSConfig`

Integration test executions using `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` were failing while running AWSConfig. The tests don't need AWSConfig to run. Tried many methods on SO of excluding AWSConfig, including:

- `@TestPropertySource(properties={"spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.path.to.AWSConfig"})`
- `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { AWSConfig.class})`
- Setting `spring.cloud.config.enabled=false`

But AWSConfig was still running (and failing). How do I exclude the bootstrapped configuration class from tests?

Test setup:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(UnitLeaderRequestController.class)
@WithMockUser
public class UnitLeaderRequestControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    MockMvc mvc;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**QUICK SOLUTION:**

Adding this annotation to the Test Class excluded the bootstrapping:

`@TestPropertySource(properties={"spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled = false"})`

**ALTERNATE SOLUTION:**

Based on [How to disable Eureka and Spring Cloud Config in a WebMvcTest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44486165/how-to-disable-eureka-and-spring-cloud-config-in-a-webmvctest/44552240#44552240)

I changed the annotation to `@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-controller-tests.properties")`

, created application-controller-tests.properties in /resources and added `spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled = false` to the file so multiple test classes could use the exclusion from 1 place.

**FURTHER THOUGHTS**

It's possible a better fix might have been to stop using META-INF/spring.factories at all, and use bootstrap-{env}.yml files. I was unsure of the implications of removing META-INF/spring.factories from the project.